# Javascript: How to convert signed Char Array to Float (maybe using IEEE754)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, ieee-754

I struggle with the result of my nodejs-JDBC-MSSQL-Binary-ResultValue.
From my database I've got this

```
 [-78,119,99,63] // this is an array of signed Chars
```

In hex, 0xB2, 0x77, 0x63, 0x3F in big endian and
0x3F6377B2 as little endian.

After conversion it has to be this:

```
 0.8885451555252075
```

But how to do convert this by using javascript or nodejs?

Kind regards

Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "typed arrays":

```
var chars = new Uint8Array([-78, 119, 99, 63])
var floats = new Float32Array(chars.buffer)
> [0.8885451555252075]
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to convert these singed chars to hex?

Comment: just pass them (answer edited) - they'll get converted to their unsigned equivalent

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks.