# How to convert Float to UintArray (IEEE754)?

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am programming a node-red function block in javascript.
I need read a float value and convert it in uint16array.
In other stackoverflow question I could see the invert case, from UintArray to float. **I need from Float to UintArray**.
[Javascript: How to convert signed Char Array to Float (maybe using IEEE754)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075424/javascript-how-to-convert-signed-char-array-to-float-maybe-using-ieee754)

```
var chars = new Uint8Array([-78, 119, 99, 63])
var floats = new Float32Array(chars.buffer)
> [0.8885451555252075]
```

Do you know How I can convert from Float to UintArray?

Best regards.

Comment: If you insert each number from the float array into the typed array it will do an automatic conversion. The question is, what kind of conversion is correct for your use case? The automatic conversion truncates the number. Is that what you want or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot put negative values into `Uint8Array`. It's for unsigned integer values from 0 to 255. So `-78` will become `178`.

Use `Int8Array` (from -128 to 127) instead.
And back conversion is straightforward:

```js
var chars = new Int8Array([-78, 119, 99, 63])
var floats = new Float32Array(chars.buffer)

console.log(floats)

var back = new Int8Array(floats.buffer)

console.log(back)
```

[See more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#Typed_array_views).

Hope it helps.